# How to get the previous and next line and discard rest of the lines including white-spaces through regex?

Tags: regex

Below is my regex code but so far I cannot fetch the desired output.

```
(?:^|\r?\n)(.*?)\s\n?r([A-Z]+)r?\n\s(.*?)(?:\r?\n|$)
```

The input:

```
      INT. JOHN AND LORI'S APARTMENT - NIGHT



      John and Lori burst in with the remains of Ted. They're

      both drenched from the rain. Lori frantically searches

      drawers for sewing materials. She finds a needle and

      thread, and John puts Ted on the table. Lori starts to

      sew him up as John watches intently.



                      LORI

       John... I don't know if this is gonna--



                      JOHN

       Just try. Please. Just try.
```

I am aiming to get the output in the following manner:

```
John... I don't know if this is gonna--

JOHN

Just try. Please. Just try.
```

Comment: You cannot match discontinuous portions of text with one match operation. Grab what you need and then post-process with another regex or using programming language means.

Comment: Also, see https://regex101.com/r/wDdBkW/1, the regex captured what you need (maybe) into 3 groups. Just concat their values the way you see fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using:
`'[^\w] ([A-Z]+\\n\\n.+\\n)'`

#### Explanation

`'[^\w]`  - Make sure no letter appers before capitalized text (e.g LORI, JOHN)
`[A-Z]+\\n\\n` - Look for a capitalized word followed by a blank line
`.+\\n` - Look for any sign that appears more than once and ends with new  line.
This finds the next line after capitalized name

### Example

Using python regex, `text` holds your entire text:

```
import re
output = re.findall('[^\w] ([A-Z]+\\n\\n.+\\n)', text)
print output
```

This will output:

> LORI
>
> John... I don't know if this is gonna--
>
> JOHN
>
> Just try. Please. Just try.

Comment: tried it before posting here but not working. is there any other work around?

Comment: ([A-Z][a-z].+\S[^\w].\s+\s.+\s\n.+)

currently trying this one... it gives the desired output but as it will differ on long sentences with multiple line breaks, so this is not accurate as well.

Comment: basically what i am trying to achieve is regardless of how may tabs or line breaks or white spaces are there, I want the output of the "capital word"(Could be anyone's name), "it's previous dialog"(can be a multiline dialog) and the "next dialog" (can be a multiline dialog) only, and excluding everything else

Comment: You're using regex to find patterns in a formatted text
If you do not know the format of the text, there is no way to determine
What part of the text you want.
How do you define "Previous dialog" or "Next dialog"?
When it follows a known format (For example two new lines then charactar's dialog) you can identify what text you need.

Comment: There is no specific pattern of how many lines to fetch from previous dialog and next dialog, the only pattern I could find for this was between two dialog there is a capital word string like(LORI, JOHN.., etc), and i want dialog between those capitals regardless of how many lines it is...